# Button doesn't disable when function is called

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm really lost with this:
In this Case the Button should diasable (`btnStart.setEnable(false)`) when it got clicked.
after this it should call a function, located in an other class.
Everything works, except that the `btnStart` doesn't disable on click but after the function ist called.

So this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonKLick) {
    if(buttonKLick.getSource() == this.btnStart){
        btnStart.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            Funktionen.fileFinder(Pfad); //The Function
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Will call the function `FileFinder` and **then** disable the button although the button should be disabled before.

Comment: And ..your question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've likely got a threading issue where your other method is taking time and locking up the Swing event thread, preventing Swing from properly painting the button as disabled. What happens if you use a background thread?

i.e.,

```
if(buttonKLick.getSource() == this.btnStart){
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Funktionen.fileFinder(Pfad); //The Function
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }).start();
}
```

---

**Edit**:

Please be sure to read: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Or use a SwingWorker as @Robin recommends. 1+ to his great answer.

Comment: @globus243: you're welcome -- just remember not to try to re-enable the JButton from within the method called on a background thread. If you in fact do desire to do this, you will want to use a SwingWorker as Robin recommends -- and you should accept his answer.

Comment: @globus243: please see edit to answer. You know, your name is a bit hard to swallow.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will disable the button right when you call `setEnabled( false )`. Just try calling `isEnabled()` before you call that function.

What you observe is that the button is only painted in disabled state after the function is executed. That is because your function occupies the one and only thread used to update the UI (the Event Dispatch Thread).

Solution: execute your function on a worker thread, for example using a `SwingWorker`. Also, read the [Swing concurrency guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). This explains in more detail what I mentioned here